# Error Stack Overflow when trying to hide buttons in navbar after user login

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

What Im trying to do is to hide the login button in masterpage header when the user logged in.
Below are the codes.

SiteMaster.Master.aspx

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SiteMaster.Master.cs" Inherits="UniSystem.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - UniSystem Database - </title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>


</head>
<body>

    <form runat="server">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="navbar-brand ps-5" runat="server" href="~/">Home</a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a runat="server" class="nav-link fs-5 gap-2" href="~/AdminModule/RegisterLecturer/Lecturer.aspx">Register Lecturer</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a runat="server" class="nav-link fs-5 gap-2" href="~/LecturerModule/LecturerWorkload/WorkloadLec.aspx">Lecturer Page</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a runat="server" class="nav-link fs-5 gap-2" href="~/Login/LoginPage.aspx">Login</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a runat="server" class="nav-link fs-5 gap-2" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end pe-5">

                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnlogin" class="btn btn-outline-danger me-md-2 fs-5"  runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Login/LoginPage.aspx">Login</asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>    
                    
                </div> 
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container body-content pt-3">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - Designed by MAMK-CI190019</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

SiteMaster.Master.aspx.cs

```
namespace UniSystem
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public LinkButton btnlogin
        {
            get
            {
                return this.btnlogin;
            }

        }
```

LoginPage.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Login" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SiteMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LoginPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="UniSystem.LoginPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Login/css/Login.css"/>    
<div style="height: 150px; width: 980px;">
   
    <h2 position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 150px;>
        Login Page  
    </h2>
   
        <asp:Label ID="lblLoginID" Runat="server" Text='ID' style="font-size: medium"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLoginID" runat="server" Width="240px"></asp:TextBox>

        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="lblLoginPass" Runat="server" Text='Password' style="font-size: medium"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLoginPass" runat="server" Width="240px" ></asp:TextBox>
    </div>       

<div class ="radiopad">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblDBSelect" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Student" Value="Student" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Lecturer" Value="Lecturer" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Admin" Value="Admin" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>

<div class ="radiopad">
    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />

    <br />

    <asp:Label ID="lblAttention" runat="server" CssClass="Note"></asp:Label>
</div>
    </asp:Content>
```

LoginPage.aspx.cs

```
namespace UniSystem
{
    public partial class LoginPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginPageC std = new LoginPageC();
            string txtloginid = txtLoginID.Text;
            string txtloginpass = txtLoginPass.Text;
            string selectTbl = rblDBSelect.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();

            {
                if (txtloginid.Trim() == "" && txtloginpass.Trim() == "")
                {
                    lblAttention.Text = "Please Insert Data Completely!";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (std.LoginValidation(txtloginid, txtloginpass, selectTbl) == false)
                    {
                        lblAttention.Text = " *Wrong Credentials";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        

                        string selTbl = std.GetSelectedTbl();
                        if (selTbl == "Lecturer")
                        {
                            Session["loginid"] = std.GetLoginID();
                            Response.Redirect("/LecturerModule/LecturerWorkload/WorkloadLec.aspx");
                        }
                        else if (selTbl == "Admin")
                        {
                            Session["loginid"] = std.GetLoginID();
                            Response.Redirect("/AdminModule/RegisterLecturer/Lecturer.aspx");
                        }
                        else if (selTbl == "Student")
                        {
                            Response.Redirect("Student.aspx");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lblAttention.Text = " *Please Select A Role";
                        }
                    }
                }       
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WorkloadLec.aspx / aka lecturer dashboard

```
<%@ Page Title="WorkloadLec" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SiteMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WorkloadLec.aspx.cs" Inherits="UniSystem.WorkloadLec" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/SiteMaster.Master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<!DOCTYPE html>
    

    <div style="height: 800px; width: 980px;">
    <h2 position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 150px;>
        Register Lecturer  
    </h2>
        <br />
              <asp:datagrid id="dgLecturerWorkload" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                BorderColor="Transparent" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="980px" ShowFooter="True"
                OnItemDataBound="dgLecturerWorkload_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="dgLecturerWorkload_ItemCommand"
                AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanged="dgLecturerWorkload_PageIndexChanged" Height="300px">
                
                  <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="Even_Row_Admin"></AlternatingItemStyle>
                
                  <HeaderStyle CssClass="Table_Header_Admin"></HeaderStyle>
                
                <Columns>

                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="No">
                            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"/>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# (dgLecturerWorkload.PageSize*dgLecturerWorkload.CurrentPageIndex)+ Container.ItemIndex+1%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="5%" />
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>


                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Subject">
                            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"/>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSubjectName" Runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SUBJECT_NAME") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="50%" />
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
                        
                    
                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Create Assignment/Tutorial">
                            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"/>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnCreateAsgnmt" Runat="server" CommandName="CreateAsgnmt" Text="Create" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="15%" />
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
  
 
                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Quiz True/False">
                            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"/>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnResultQuizTF" Runat="server" CommandName="ResultQuizTF" Text="Result" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnCreateQuizTF" Runat="server" CommandName="CreateQuizTF" Text="Create/View Quiz" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="15%" />
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>


                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Quiz Objective">
                            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"/>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnResultQuizObj" Runat="server" CommandName="ResultQuizObj" Text="Result" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnCreateQuizObj" Runat="server" CommandName="CreateQuizObj" Text="Create/View Quiz" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="15%" />
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>

                </Columns>

            <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages" />
 
    </asp:datagrid>
        

        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLecturerWorkload" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblAttention" runat="server" CssClass="Note"></asp:Label>
             
                
</div>



        <div class="center" style="width: 980px; height: 59px;">
        
            Centered
        </div>


</asp:Content>
```

WorkloadLec.aspx.cs

```
namespace UniSystem
{
    public partial class WorkloadLec : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {

            if (Session["loginid"] != null)
            {  
                {
                    Master.btnlogin.Visible = false;
                }         
            }

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                SetupSubject();
            }

        }

        public void SetupSubject()
        {
            dgLecturerWorkload.ShowFooter = true;

            WorkloadLecC std = new WorkloadLecC();
            DataSet ds = std.GetDisplaySubj();
            dgLecturerWorkload.DataSource = ds.Tables["SUBJECT"];
            dgLecturerWorkload.DataBind();


            ArrayList arAnswerEyeList = std.SelecSubj("", "");
            ddlLecturerWorkload.DataSource = arAnswerEyeList;
            ddlLecturerWorkload.DataTextField = "Value";
            ddlLecturerWorkload.DataValueField = "Key";
            ddlLecturerWorkload.DataBind();
        }


        protected void dgLecturerWorkload_PageIndexChanged(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            dgLecturerWorkload.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            SetupSubject();
        }



        protected void dgLecturerWorkload_ItemDataBound(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Item.FindControl("DeleteUser") != null)
            {
                ((Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnDeleteUser")).Attributes.Add("onClick", "return confirm('Are you sure wish to delete the data?');");
            }


        }
protected void dgEdit_Student(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            dgLecturerWorkload.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
            SetupSubject();
        }

        protected void dgCancel_Student(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            dgLecturerWorkload.EditItemIndex = -1;
            SetupSubject();
        }
}
}
}
```

So when a user clicks the login button in the masterpage, it will redirect to loginpage.aspx, then from the login page, it redirects to WorkloadLec.aspx like a dashboard. As the dashboard also displays the same navbar from the masterpage, i want to hide the login button after user logged in. However, StackOverflowException is being thrown at the return.this.btnlogin.

I follow all the steps in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrKZ2YFsr8s but still cant get it to work. Please help me.

Comment: You [posted too much code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/). You haven't [provided debugging details](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/). Both are symptoms of [doing no debugging](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). You have to do that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there another protected (probably auto generated) variable you meant to reference? The getter is referencing itself, which is causing your StackOverflowExecption.

```
public LinkButton btnlogin
{
    get {
      return this.btnlogin; <-- this should be another variable
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly this. The btnlogin is referencing to the button control. The method name shouldnt be the same with the getter. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

In your SiteMaster class you have a property named btnlogin that consequently returns itself each time you call it. I mean after the first usage of btnLogin a chain of requests will be created to return btnLogin -> btnLogin -> btnLogin -> ...

Answer (score 0):

The master page load event DOES fire when you navigate to  new web page (a standard master + child web page).

So, all you really have to do is to hide/show menu options based on their logon.

I mean it is VERY common to have a Hodge podge of menu items that should show, or not show based on their "role" memberships.

So, just add "ID" tags to the bootstrap menu system - and then you can simple use code behind based on role(s) membership to hide/or show menu items.

So your typical main bootstrap menu will look like this:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
   <li id="m1" runat="server"><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
   <li id="m2" runat="server"><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
   <li id="m3" runat="server" style="display:none!important"><a runat="server" href="~/Upload">Upload Files</a></li>
```

Of course lots more menus - some of them drop downs. But the SIMPLE idea here is to add that "id" tag, and runat server.

Now, in the master page load - it is a simple matter to hide/show menu items based on their member ship in security roles like this:

```
   If Roles.IsUserInRole("Portal") Then
        'Me.PortalLink.Visible = True
        Me.m4.Visible = True        ' show logged in portal tab
        Me.m3.Visible = False       ' hide general upload tab
        Me.m8.Visible = True
        Me.mAdmin.Visible = Roles.IsUserInRole("SiteAdmin")
        Me.btnProofMainSite.Visible = True
        Me.m8.Visible = True
```

So in above - the if/then is for a valid Portal user, but even inside, some of the menu options are chosen based on IsUserInRole. So in some cases, I have a if/then block for a given role, and in other cases, I directly assing the visible property based on the isUserInRole security group.

So, as you build up and add new menu items to the master page menu, then just add simple clean plan jane code to hide or show menu items. As long as you add a "id" and runat server, then clean simple code based on their roles can hide/show menu items based on their role membership.

So, you don't need (or want) to wire up code directly in the logon screen. All you do is let them logon, and when you re-direct to any new page (which of course is a master/child page), then the master page on-load event fires, and you hide/show whatever you want -  including the logon name, or menus or whatever. The on-load code runs for each new page you jump to (post backs ON that page as a general rule don't re-run the master page load - but that's ok too).